# Suppose $A$ is a $2x2$ matrix and ${\bf x}=(x_1, x_2)$. What does "$f(Ax)$ is supermodular" mean?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, economics

Suppose $A$ is a $2x2$ matrix, e.g., $A=\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}  \\
a_{21} & a_{22}  \\
\end{vmatrix}$, and ${\bf x}=(x_1, x_2)$. Suppose $f()$ is continuous and twice differentiable.

What does "$f(Ax)$ is supermodular" mean?

For example, if $f(x)$ is supermodular, we have the cross partials of $f()$ with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$ nonnegative.

How can we similarly represent $f(Ax)$ supermodular in terms of the second partial and cross partial derivatives?

Note: I am interested in the expression for the continuous case and not the general lattice definition if possible.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you, @DietrichBurde, I edited the question and used MathJax.